# Pandas Aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and have been using it for a class, however I am certainly not versed in Panda-ese.

Let's say I have a data frame as such:

```
accord = pd.Series({'Manufacturer' : 'Honda',
                'Model' : 'Accord',
                'Drivetrain': 'FWD'})

civic = pd.Series({'Manufacturer' : 'Honda',
                    'Model' : 'Civic',
                    'Drivetrain': 'FWD'})


focus = pd.Series({'Manufacturer' : 'Ford',
                    'Model' : 'Focus',
                    'Drivetrain': 'FWD'})

mustang = pd.Series({'Manufacturer' : 'Ford',
                    'Model' : 'Mustang',
                    'Drivetrain': 'RWD'})

cars_df = pd.DataFrame([accord, civic, focus, mustang])
```

And what I'm ultimately trying to get is a list comprising the total models for each manufacturer and how many front wheel drive vehicles they make.

So, I pull out a series and make a new data frame:

```
manufacturer_s = cars_df['Manufacturer'].unique()
manufacturer_df = pd.DataFrame(index=manufacturer_s)
```

I add empty columns for the information I seek:

```
manufacturer_df['FWD MODEL COUNT'] = 0
manufacturer_df['MODEL COUNT'] = 0
```

And I use 'iterrows' to populate this data:

```
for manufacturer, row in manufacturer_df.iterrows():
    row['MODEL COUNT'] = 
          len(cars_df[cars_df['Manufacturer'] == manufacturer])
    row['FWD MODEL COUNT'] =  
          len(cars_df[(cars_df['Manufacturer'] == manufacturer) &
                      (cars_df['Drivetrain'] == 'FWD')])
```

Now, my output is as follows:

```
       FWD MODEL COUNT  MODEL COUNT
Honda                2            2
Ford                 1            2
```

(EDIT: I found a typo, so this part does work) Now, not only is this verbose (and potentially slow), but it doesn't feel very "panda-esque."

Alternatively, I tried the following:

```
manufacturer_df['MODEL COUNT'] = manufacturer_df.apply(lambda car: 
         len(cars_df[cars_df['Manufacturer'] == car.index]), axis=1)
manufacturer_df['FWD MODEL COUNT'] = manufacturer_df.apply(lambda car: 
   len(cars_df[(cars_df['Manufacturer'] == car.index) & 
               (cars_df['Drivetrain'] == 'FWD')]), axis=1)
```

Which doesn't work at all... So, how should I do this and (additionally) what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want *sum* instead of *len*. Think about it it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby().agg()` where you can summarize each column with a different aggregation function. You can calculate the unique models for each Manufacturer with `pd.Series.nunique` and calculates the total number of FWD vehicles by counting the number of trues in `x == "FWD"` for each group:

```
(cars_df.groupby("Manufacturer").agg({"Model": "nunique",     
                                      "Drivetrain": lambda x: (x == "FWD").sum()}))

#              Model    Drivetrain
#Manufacturer       
#       Ford       2             1
#      Honda       2             2
```